# how to remove the rows which has non-numeric data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Amount column consists of texts

[image]

I have a column  which is supposed to be an integer which is saved as object in the DataFrame. I tried to remove the columns which are not numeric by using the below codes:

```
df[df.columns[8]] = df[df.columns[8]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(float).astype(int).dropna()
```

But the code is not working. I tried to replace the texts with 0 but its not working.

Comment: Don't post links to images, paste the relevant parts of your data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will render string rows to NAs.

```
df["Amount in USD"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Amount in USD"], errors='coerce')
```

Then just filter out rows which has NAs.

```
df = df[df["Amount in USD"].notnull()]
```

Comment: I tried it earlier but its not working.

df["Amount in USD"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Amount in USD"], errors='coerce') is converting all the rows into NaN values as the int values are saved as text in the dataframe.

Comment: I tried it and it is working perfectly. It converts only string cells to NAs.

Comment: yeah the numbers were saved in the form of string. so even they are being converted to NAs